Blender Geometry Nodes Dissolve Effect - Random Displace Some Instances?
i'm attempting to make a dissolve effect that is driven by proximity to an Empty.
So far, i've created a mesh to volume, then populated that with points/instances of a brick.  I have the Empty shrinking the brick instances when in close proximity to the Empty.
The problem is that it looks too organized, perfect, and unnatural.
So, how do I randomly displace some of the instances affected by the Empty?
Each time I try, either the entire array of instances transports to another location (which i cant' have, because i'ts part of a scene whose composition is already established), or they dont randomly displace, opting instead to each follow the same path.
This is my first attempt:

It give a cool effect, but the entire building scoots away, not just the bricks affected by the empty.  It also seeems to displace using an organized sine wave or something similar, not random.
Here is my node setup:

Thanks!  There are other effects im trying for related to this topic that affect this one, but Stack Exchange wouldn't let me include them all in one post. Please see my post history if you're curious and want to help out.
Thank you!

"the entire array of instances transports to another location" because the Translate Instance node is adding the Position to ... the Position. An offset, not a position, should be used instead. Perhaps the difference between the Position and Object Info>Location ?

Ah okay, i'll try that out!  I'm really ignorant about what exactly a lot of these nodes do

This didn't work unfortunately.    I simplified the geometry noes by taking away the scale stuff, and only focusing on the translate.  I cant seem to get the bricks to randomly translate, they simply shift over in one uniform direction.    I'm not savvy enough about what each node does to know how to achieve what i'm after

So I added a "Set Position" node, and plugged a Random Value into the Offest, which gives a good result all over the model.  But when I try to plug a Distance/Empty setup into the Position slot on the "Set Postition" node, it doesnt work.  Instead of having the area close to the Empty be affected, the entire model becomes a thin string of instances

Im not sure how to make it affect only the area close to the Empty

Do you want full 3D random displacement, or some random radial displacement (like an contraction towards the "Empty" origin) ?

Do you want a static rendering or a dynamic one ? If dynamic, do you want a reversible process (i.e. the building is unmodified once the Empty is away) or an irreversible process (i.e. zero scaled bricks never show again) ?

Here is my suggestion (this is very free and could be made in many different ways).

Instead of "translate" instances, you need to "set position"

Why? You're using "location" as a result. If you set a position to its own location, it remains, but if you "translate" by its location, you "double the location".


Don't use a mix color if you want a mix vector (won't change the result, I guess)
Add a random value to the position of the empty, so each instance follows in a different pattern
Looks like your connections in the mix are swapped, which also makes me thing that the image you showed and the node setup don't match.



